# Using Intellisense in Visual C++ 2008 Express. Intellisense for one project not available when editing file in another project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, intellisense

I have a multiple vcproj solution going and it seems that no other project's intellisense information is available when editing a file in another project.  However when I'm within a file in a project, all intellisense information is available for that project.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing a using directive or a reference ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the other project's namespace in the file with a using directive in order for the intellisense to show for the other project.

Comment: There is another assignment someone else is working on where they use a similar multiple vcproj solution and the intellisense info shows up for them, regardless of the project they're currently in. I couldn't find any differences in our solutions or vcprojs, other than files included in one project.